# Python BeautifulSoup: get content inside tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

My BeautifulSoup request returns the following content:

```
<td align="left">
<div><div class="dgreen"></div><div class="dorange"></div><div class="dred"></div><div class="dorange"></div></div>
</td>
```

With Python BeautifulSoup, how would you get the "dgreen", "dorange", "dred" labels ?
Because those are not text, I don't manage to get them and store them in a list.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls revise you question, its incomplete. Ok you miss the indent, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

To get the word in attribute class

After you get divs, then iterate

```
divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": True})
for div in divs:
    print(div.attrs["class"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use select with a selector that ensure the div has a class. You can use set to get only unique

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <div>
   <div class="dgreen"></div>
   <div class="dorange"></div>
   <div class="dred"></div>
   <div class="dorange"></div>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
labels = [item['class'] for item in soup.select('div[class]')]
print(labels)
result = set(map(tuple, labels))
print(result)
```

Comment: Fantastic.

Many thanks guys.